# Using Monotouch with iSQL SDK

Tags: xamarin.ios

Is it possible to use the iSQL SDK (www.mobilefoo.com) with MonoTouch considering that the iSQL SDK is a client library meant for use with XCODE and objective-c code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - not a complex task but a bit time-consuming. Although you should only have to do it once (until they extend their libraries.)

Instructions on how to bind to Objective C libraries and types are here: http://wiki.monotouch.net/HowTo/Interop/Consuming_3rd_Party_ObjC_Libraries

It might well be worth contacting mobilefoo about this too as I'd imagine they'd be interested and might even help.